# python3 on Raspberry pi

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, mitmproxy

I'm trying to run mitmproxy on Raspberry Pi to run some tests however although Python3 is installed and python2 is uninstalled, I keep getting an error when trying to run mitmproxy - mitmproxy requires Python 3.6 or higher.

pi@raspberrypi: python3 -V Python3.7.2

Anyone has ever met the issue before?

Are you aware of any similar tools that I can use instead of this one?

Comment: Try installing python 3.6 on the pi: `https://gist.github.com/dschep/24aa61672a2092246eaca2824400d37f`

Comment: Do you get the same result if you run `python -V` ?

Comment: i will try to install python3.6 and see how it goes

Comment: What is the context of `pi@raspberrypi: python3 -V Python3.7.2` in your question? Is that your own Pi, or taken from a tutorial you're following?

Comment: Don't install Python 3.6. If anything, you want to upgrade to Buster to get 3.7. It's not ready for release yet but at least system things will work with that version of Python. Replace `stretch` with `buster` in `/etc/apt/sources.list` and run `apt distr-upgrade`. You'll get Python 3.7.

Comment: no luck, when trying to install the proxy I am getting this warning, and a couple of others: " pip is configured with locations that require TLS/SSL, however the ssl module in Python is not available."

Comment: Raspbian Buster is now available on the Raspberry Pi Official website! See my answer below for the link. (Worked for me)

Answer (score 0):

I have had a similar issue before. What I did was I wrote `python 3 [what you want to run here]` Instead of just writing python.

**If that does not work:**
Upgrade your Raspberry Pi to Raspbian Buster. [click to go to official Raspbian Buster download page](https://www.raspberrypi.org/downloads/raspbian/) (format your sd card then install the new Raspbian onto that sd card and use that sd card in the Rpi) then run `python3 [your code here]` on your Raspberry Pi with up to date Raspbian Buster.

Hope this helps!